# Does Oko, Thief of Crowns come in a planeswalker deck, or only as an individual card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-planeswalkers

I can't find anything about this on Google, Bing or Stack Exchange. Does [Oko, Thief of Crowns](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOko%2c%20Thief%20of%20Crowns%5d) come with a planeswalker deck, or separately? By separately, I mean in booster packs and stuff like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's 'just' a regular Throne of Eldraine card, found in boosters and tournament packs – if you're lucky, of course; those cards are always random.

There *is* a preconstructed Throne of Eldraine deck with an Oko planeswalker, but it's [Oko, the Trickster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOko%2c%20the%20Trickster%5d). You can find those decks e.g. [here](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Throne_of_Eldraine#Preconstructed_decks).

Comment: Yeah, I have Oko, the Trickster. He's awesome. Definitely worth the 15 bucks I paid for that deck.

Answer (score 1):

No, [Oko, the Trickster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOko%2c%20the%20Trickster%5d) is the version of Oko in the planeswalker deck, not Oko, Thief of Crowns. Planeswalker deck planeswalkers are different from the planeswalkers in their set and are numbered above the number of cards in that set, but still considered part of it for standard/modern legality. The planeswalkers in these decks are generally considered to be overcosted, less powerful and less useful than their set counterparts.

The planeswalker deck planeswalkers to date:

- Kaladesh: [Chandra, Pyrogenius](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%2c%20Pyrogenius%5d) and [Nissa, Nature's Artisan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNissa%2c%5d%2b%5bNature%27s%5d%2b%5bArtisan%5d)
- Aether Revolt: [Ajani, Valiant Protector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAjani%2c%20Valiant%20Protector%5d) and [Tezzeret, Master of Metal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTezzeret%2c%20Master%20of%20Metal%5d)
- Amonkhet: [Gideon, Martial Paragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%2c%20Martial%20Paragon%5d) and [Liliana, Death Wielder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLiliana%2c%20Death%20Wielder%5d)
- Hour of Devastation: [Nicol Bolas, the Deceiver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNicol%20Bolas%2c%20the%20Deceiver%5d) and [Nissa, Genesis Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNissa%2c%20Genesis%20Mage%5d)
- Ixalan: [Huatli, Dinosaur Knight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHuatli%2c%20Dinosaur%20Knight%5d) and [Jace, Ingenious Mind-Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%2c%20Ingenious%20Mind-Mage%5d)
- Rivals of Ixalan: [Angrath, Minotaur Pirate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAngrath%2c%20Minotaur%20Pirate%5d) and [Vraska, Scheming Gorgon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVraska%2c%20Scheming%20Gorgon%5d)
- Dominaria: [Chandra, Bold Pyromancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%2c%20Bold%20Pyromancer%5d) and [Teferi, Timebender](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%2c%20Timebender%5d)
- Core Set 2019: [Ajani, Wise Counselor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAjani%2c%20Wise%20Counselor%5d), [Tezzeret, Cruel Machinist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTezzeret%2c%20Cruel%20Machinist%5d), [Liliana, the Necromancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLiliana%2c%20the%20Necromancer%5d), [Sarkhan, Dragonsoul](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSarkhan%2c%20Dragonsoul%5d), and [Vivien of the Arkbow](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVivien%20of%20the%20Arkbow%5d)
- Guilds of Ravnica: [Ral, Caller of Storms](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRal%2c%20Caller%20of%20Storms%5d) and [Vraska, Regal Gorgon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVraska%2c%20Regal%20Gorgon%5d)
- Ravnica Allegiance: [Gideon, the Oathsworn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%2c%20the%20Oathsworn%5d) and [Jace, Arcane Strategist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%2c%20Arcane%20Strategist%5d)
- Core Set 2020: [Ajani, Inspiring Leader](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAjani%2c%20Inspiring%20Leader%5d), [Mu Yanling, Celestial Wind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMu%20Yanling%2c%20Celestial%20Wind%5d), [Sorin, Vampire Lord](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSorin%2c%20Vampire%20Lord%5d), [Chandra, Flame's Fury](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%2c%5d%2b%5bFlame%27s%5d%2b%5bFury%5d), and [Vivien, Nature's Avenger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVivien%2c%5d%2b%5bNature%27s%5d%2b%5bAvenger%5d)
- Throne of Eldraine: [Rowan, Fearless Sparkmage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRowan%2c%20Fearless%20Sparkmage%5d) and Oko, the Trickster.